# Gradle java-platform plugin and platform definition

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use the `java-platform` plugin to share dependency constraints in a multi-module project. What I would like to do is set up a module named `platform` which I can import using `platform(project(":platform"))` in other modules. Additionally I would like to import a BOM into my platform project using `platform("group-id:of-the-bom:and-version")`.

An example is the following structure:

```groovy
// settings.gradle
include("platform")
include("consumer")
```

```groovy
// platform/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java-platform'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        api platform("org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-javaee8:15.0.1.Final")
    }
}
```

```groovy
// consumer/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform(project(":platform"))
    implementation "org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec"
}
```

When I run `gradle consumer:dependencies` I get output containing the following:

```
compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- project :platform
\--- org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec FAILED
```

It seems as though the `platform` module is not "re-exporting" constraints which were pulled in through the usage of `platform()`.

I have found two "workarounds" which don't really solve my problem but seem to indicate that the issue is the usage of `platform()` together with the `java-platform` plugin:

1. Replace `implementation platform(project(":platform"))` with `implementation platform("org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-javaee8:15.0.1.Final")` in `consumer/build.gradle`.
2. Put an explicit entry in `platform/build.gradle` such as `api org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec:1.0.1.Final`.

Is the `java-platform` plugin not intended to be used in this way, or is there some configuration option I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Importing a BOM in Gradle means that you want to *depend* on the BOM to get its provided *constraints* applied.

What you add by default to a platform are *constraints*. But constraints only appear in a graph if and only if there is a matching *dependency* declaration. Also constraints *only* inform about the module targeted. They never bring any transitive information.

So what you need to do is declare that your `platform` project *depends* on the BOM. It will then export its constraints as expected.

```
// platform/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java-platform'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

javaPlatform {
    // Declare that your platform contains dependencies
    allowDependencies()
}

dependencies {
    // This is a dependency on the BOM that will bring its constraints transitively
    api platform("org.wildfly.bom:wildfly-javaee8:15.0.1.Final")
    constraints {
        // Additional constraints not covered by the platform above go here
    }
}
```